# View a Fullscreen image after onClick button

Tags: android

I'm developing my first app so I'm a newbie of Android programming.

I have a button that will turn off my screen with the command

`Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c input keyevent 26");`

but the command takes about 2 seconds to turn off de screen.
So I want that immediately after clicking on the button, before launching the screen-off command will be showed a fullscreen black image, to simulate the screen off. Maybe after launching the command, with a little delay of 5seconds I have to take the image away. How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, prepare an `ImageView` in your layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    ...
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@color/colorAccent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

notice set the initial visibility of `ImageView` is **gone**.

Then in the `OnClickListener` of button:

```
       yourImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c input keyevent 26");
                yourImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }, 5000); //after 5 seconds
```

Comment: 1. ImageView is now match_parent and it keeps Titlebar and system StatusBar Visible (also NavigationBar for who has one).
2. Some buttons and switches on layout keeps being on top